Analyzing the functional form of $g(x)$ and its linear combination properties
Given a real function of a real variable $g=g(x)$ such that
$$
3g(x) + 2g(1-x) = 9 + 2x,
$$
calculate $g(2)$. Since the function $g$ depends on the variable $x$ and $1-x$, we can assume that it is
$$
g(x) = ax + b(1-x),
$$
with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, meaning that $g$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $1-x$. By substituting this $g$ into the above equation, we obtain $g(2) = 5$ using the polynomial identity principle.
Can we theoretically justify why $g$ must be a linear combination of $x$ and $1-x$? Does this relate to the theory of functions or other branches (ex.: functional analysis)?

You actually assumed that $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $1$, or we can say that $g(x)=\alpha x+\beta$. Put this and you'll obtain the same answer.
Now why do we get the same answer in both cases? It's because $\dim(P_1)=2$ and both $\{1,x\}$ and $\{x,1-x\}$ are basis of $P_1$ where $P_1$ is set of all polynomials of degree $1$ or less.

Nice response. I understand it, but it's definitely not a reply suitable for high school students (ages 17-18). Thank you very much.

@Sebastiano then you shouldn't have included the linear algebra tag in your post

The algebra tag is correct. I was thinking about something related to dimensions that I studied 31 years ago. I still remember that the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n[x]$ is $E = {1, x, x^2, x^3, \ldots, x^n}$.

@Sebastiano oh damn, you're quite older than me...I thought you're a high school student...silly me

Don't worry about it. :-). You aren't slly: surely.

First, from what you did, denote $h(x) = g(x) -(ax +b(1-x))$, then
$$\implies 3h(x)+2h(1-x) =\underbrace{3g(x)+2g(1-x)}_{=2x+9}-\left((a-b)x + (2a+3b) \right)$$
It suffices to chose $(a,b) = (3,1)$ and then with $h(x) = g(x) -(3x+(1-x))$, we have:
$$3h(x) + 2h(1-x) = 0 \tag{1}$$
Second, we will prove that $h(x)  =0$. Replace $x$ by $(1-x)$ in $(1)$, we obtain:
$$3h(1-x) + 2h(x) = 0 \tag{2}$$
From $(1)(2)$, we deduce : $h(x) = h(1-x)$ and then $h(x) = h(1-x) = 0$ for all $x$.
We conclude that $$\color{red}{g(x) =h(x) + (3x+(1-x))= 2x+1}$$
and $g(2) = 5$

Why do you use $h(x) = g(x) -(ax +b(1-x))$? This is exactly what I'm interested in. Why must
$g$ be a linear combination?

@Sebastiano With that, we can obtain $(1)$. And why we do that? My answer is from experiences coming from a lot of practices (this technique is frequently used in math competition).

Indeed, in the mathematics textbook for high school students, the exercise is taken from a mathematics competition. Thank you again for your contribution.

$$3g(x)+2g(1-x)=2x+9$$
Do $x\to 1-x$
$$\implies 3g(1-x)+2g(x)=2(1-x)+9=11-2x$$
Put $g(x)=A$ and $g(1-x)=B$
$\implies 3A+2B=9+2x$ 
and $3B+2A=11-2x$
Solving gives
$$A=2x+1=g(x)$$
Hence $$\boxed{g(2)=5}$$

EDIT:
So we obtained that $g$ is a linear polynomial. Hence it can be expressed as a linear combination of the elements of the basis of its vector space (here it's $P_1$). And as I already said that that $\{x,1-x\}$ is a basis of $P_1$, hence $g$ is expressible as a linear combination of $x$ and $1-x$

this is nice +1, you generalized my answer

I don't think there's need to assume $g$ as a linear combination of $x$ and $1-x$. Since $3g(x)+2g(1-x)=9+2x$ holds for all $x$, then evaluating at $x=-1$ and $x=2$ you have:
\begin{cases}3g(-1)+2g(2)=7 \\3g(2)+2g(-1)=13 \end{cases} Solving the system yields $g(2)=5$.
